# Hide portion of div that later rises with hover pop-up animation (CSS only)

Tags: css, popup, hover

Reference codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XbzJyR

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 100px 0 0 50px;
  padding: 0;
  background: green;
}

.hover {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

.container:hover .hover {
  animation: up-bump 0.4s ease; 

  top: 0px;
}
```

Can anyone please show me how to hide the red portion of the container that extends past the green tile? I want to create a thumbnail effect such that only "Test" and part of the red background surrounding Test appears first in the tile, and upon hovering over the tile, the red background moves upwards and fills the entire tile. In short, the lower 50px of the red tile should not appear as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `overflow: hidden;` to the container will fix this.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 100px 0 0 50px;
  padding: 0;
  overflow:hidden;
  background: green;
}

.hover {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

.container:hover .hover {
  animation: up-bump 0.4s ease; 

  top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="hover">
    <h3>Test</h3>
    <p>Hello there!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```